# Can't connect to FTP from external machine

Tags: virtual-machines, ftp, port, connect

We are trying to create an FTP site on our Azure VM.  Here are the steps we have taken:

From the VM

- From Server Manager we added new features.  Web Server (IIS), FTP Server, FTP Service
- From IIS we have added FTP site, setup FTP Firewall with data channel ports of 7157-7160 with external IP address as our VM Public IP, selected file folder for FTP
- We added port 21 and ports 7157-7160 to Windows Firewall as new inbound rules
- I restarted FTP service

From Azure portal

- I selected VM and clicked on networking and added inbound port rule for FTP port 21 and FTP Data ports 7157-7160

Results:
I can go to cmd prompt from VM and connect to ftp and pull directory but when I try to connect via filezilla outside the VM, it will not connect and times out.  When using a port checking tool, port 21 fails.  I can access port 3389 and 80 fine.

Comment: Open the filezilla screen log and show the response to the PASV or EPSV command for the connection that is timing out.

Answer (score -1):

FTP is two ports - 20 and 21, not just 21.

However - Try as HARD as you can to NOT use ftp.  It is woefully insecure and problematic, with no way to have passwords or any kind of security or integrity, and heaps of your users will have problems trying to access your files (e.g. a huge proportion of public wifi block all FTP access, and lots of VPNs fall over on FTP too)

Use HTTPS instead - works everywhere, solves everything, no sketchy exposing your machines and users to swathes of exploits needed.

Comment: Why use HTTPS instead of SFTP?